# Hiding Columns in Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 Beta to design a site, and am stuck on a responsive-utility.  Back in Bootstrap 3 it was: `hidden-xs` `hidden-md`, etc.

Bootstrap 4.0 Alpha added -up and -down: `hidden-sm-down` `hidden-md-up` to these classes [Resonsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/), but I can't find a way to make this functionality work with Bootstrap 4 Beta.

If I wanted to hide the following columns on sm and xs displays using only Bootstrap 4.0 Beta, how would one go about it?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-4">
    <p>Here is my text</p>
</div>
```

I've combed the [Bootstrap 4 Beta Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and tried many of the old ways and a bevvy of imagined ways to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap v4 Beta removed most of the responsive utilities to which your post refers.  Instead you need to rely on their display classes:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-4 d-none d-md-block">
    <p>Here is my text</p>
</div>
```

`d-none` sets the display to none for all viewpoints, while `d-md-block` sets the display to block-level for medium breakpoints (and greater).  At the risk of veering into opinion territory this seems less intuitive but they provide some reasoning behind this logic in the Alpha documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities